# What kind of vipassana retreats do you recommend in South East Asia?

Tags: vipassana, meditation-insight, retreat

I've been meditating for 2.5 years, and have done two retreats before (Goenka and Gil Fronsdal). I'm looking forward to expanding to my understanding of the practice in South East Asia. I was wondering which 10 day retreat people here recommend for westerners (i.e. English is available, and there isn't any esoteric content being taught).

My most likely bet seems to be Suan Mokkh in Thailand, but was wondering if there are others in the Theravada tradition that are recommended by people here (i.e. Burma, or other places in Thailand)

An up to date list of centers would also be appreciated. Most of the information I've been able to gather through googling seems quite out-dated.

Comment: What kind of practice are you hoping to undertake during retreat? There are many different types of meditation offered by different traditions, such as Goenka style Vipassana, Mahasi Sayadaw style Vipassana, Anapanasati, Metta, etc...

Comment: You can find Goenka South East Asian retreats [here](https://www.dhamma.org/en-US/locations/directory#035)

Comment: This question seems to be, "what kind of vipissana retreat do you recommend?",  not, "where are they?"

Comment: I guess I don't exactly now what I want. I think I want something different from Goenka, since I've already experienced that. Deepening anapanasati seems skillful. I'm looking for a place that is flexible in terms of your length of your stay, i.e. if the practice is unfolding in such a way that I can do more, I could stay there and practice more.

Answer (score 3):

If you come to Sri Lanka, there's nice place up in hill country called the [Rathmalkanda Meditation Center for Insight Knowledge](http://meditation.lk/). The head monk there is venerable Madawala Upali thera who has been a meditation teacher over 40 years. The main meditation taught there is the Vipassana(insight) meditation of the Mahasi Sayadaw tradition. But venerable Upali also teaches Anapanasati, Kasina and other Samatha(tranquility) meditation techniques as well.

Answer (score 1):

I will be taking a retreat near Kuala Lumpur starting 1st December (Mahasi style). Full retreat is one month, but no problem leaving early. Let me know if you are interested in more details.

Answer (score 1):

Goenka's Vipassana techniques is very effective, hence I would recommend to stick with it. Also a similar techniques is taught at [International Meditation Centre](http://www.internationalmeditationcentre.org/global/index.html).

Also [Suan Mokkh](http://www.suanmokkh-idh.org/) is a pretty good place to study Anapana I would expect though I have not been there [Ven. Buddhadasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhadasa)'s books on this are very effective.

Also if you are going to Burma you can try [Pa-Auk Forest Monastery](http://www.paaukforestmonastery.org/). Also you can try out Mogok Sayadaw's Meditation techniques, there many monasteries but little web presence hence you might need to do a bit more searching.

Also have a look at [World Buddhist Directory](http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/). This might help you find more centres. If you are interested in coming to Sri Lanka there is a directory of meditation centres here: [Information about Meditation Centers in Sri Lanka](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/Info-Meditation-Centers-Sri-Lanka2013.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I would look for monastery that is absent of tiracchana vijja 
(tiracchana literally means non-human animal, or crossed animals (animals that cant make progress in Dhamma). tiracchana vijja means low art.  Or practices that crossed with path to nirvana.     Also monasteries that do not have donation box every 10 ft.  Ajahn Cha's monasteries are nice.

the appendices of this books shows tiracchana vijja or wrong livelihood for Bhikkhus.  [tiracchana vijja](https://www.scribd.com/doc/86140815/76/Twen-one-Kinds-of-Wrong-Livelihood-for-Bhikkhus)